# listview menu in android

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, menu, controls

I'm attempting to create an application menu in an android mobile app which looks similar to the one used by the Android eBay application.

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ebay.mobile&hl=en

Its groups menu items together, i.e. Saved Searches & Favourite sellers

Can anyone give me any points on how to start creating a control similar to this?  What base class to use etc.

Any information would be most welcome.  I've been using android for about 1 yr now, so have some experience - quite new to creating controls through.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)? I think you can implement it using that widget.

Here are some examples/tutorials:

1. [Working with the ExpandableListView](http://qtcstation.com/2011/03/working-with-the-expandablelistview-part-1/)
2. [ExpandableListView](http://coderzheaven.com/2011/04/expandable-listview-in-android-using-simpleexpandablelistadapter-a-simple-example/)
3. [ExpandableList1](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html)
4. [ExpandableList2](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList2.html)
5. [ExpandableList3](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList3.html)

Comment: Thx for the answer.  Appreciated for another project I'm working on.  For this however, I've use a list view and styled it with a custom shape;